Understanding Song of Songs 4:16-5:1 from three character view
There is a three character interpretation of the Song of Solomon, which says that the shepherd, called "beloved" (1:7, 2:16, 6:2, 6:3) and the king (Solomon), not called "beloved" direcly (1:4, 1:5, 1:12, 3:7-11, 8:11-12), are different characters. But there is a passage that seems to me problematic for that. In 4:16 she asks the beloved to enter his garden. In 5:1 he enters and calls her "bride", and Solomon had wedding in 3:11, so the man called "beloved" would be Solomon. How would you reconcile this from the three character view?

Kings are often called shepherds in the OT. This tends to work against the idea that she is in love with the shepherd rather than the king.

Which king is called a shepherd? If you mean David, then he was a called a shepherd  (1 Samuel 17:34) before he became a king (2 Samuel 2:4). We need an example when a man is called a king and a shepherd at the same time

Please, answer my question

I do not see the three character interpretation of the Song of Songs, the "Allegorical Interpretation", "Christological Interpretation" and "Literal Interpretation" as conflicting with each other. Fundamentally, all are based on a literally understanding of the context.
Consider the "Song of Songs" as a drama that employs a "flashbacks" technique in its storytelling. For example, SOS 4:1-5:1 is an episode that serves as a flashback to events before the wedding. In this passage, The "Beloved" asks for marriage, beginning with praise for his bride in SOS 4:1-7. From SOS 4:8-12, he repeatedly calls her "my bride".
In SOS 4:13-5:1, a beautiful garden is described, which can be interpreted either literally or allegorically. Whether this episode is viewed allegorically as God's love for Israel, Christologically as Jesus' love for the Church, or simply as the love between a couple, all interpretations are synchronized, emphasizing "True Love" in the context of marriage.
